# Fade out on a pseudo element with CSS

Tags: css

So I want my ::before pseudo element to fade out when I un-hover. It fades in as it should, but the fade out doesn't work at all. I've tried all of the solutions on here but none of them don't seem to be working. Is it something specific for pseudo elements? 
Thank you in advance!

```
.navigation {

margin-right: 6rem;


&__list {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;        
    color: $color-grey-light;
    font-weight: 300;
    width: 30vw;
}

&__item {
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    transition: all .2s;
    position: relative;

    &:hover {
        color: $color-white;
    }

    &::before {
        content: "";
        width: 1rem;
        position: absolute;
        color: $color-blue;
        transform: translateY(3.6rem);
        border-radius: 1rem ;
        background-color: $color-black-light;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all .3s ease-out;
    }

    &:hover::before {
        background-color: $color-blue;
        height: .5rem;
        left: 15%;
        width: 70%;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: all .3s;            
    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this is what you've intended to do.

Setting `content: '';` is necessary on a pseudo-element. Also you had to remove `transition` from the `:hover::before` to enable the transition to work on mouse out.

Finally, there were rules that needed to be kept in both hover and mouseout, like `width`, `height`, and `left`.

```
.navigation {
  margin-right: 6rem;
  $color-grey-light: #555;
  $color-white: #fff;
  $color-blue: #00F;
  $color-black-light: #333;

  &__list {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    color: $color-grey-light;
    font-weight: 300;
    width: 30vw;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }

  &__item {
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    position: relative;

    &:hover {
      color: $color-white;
    }

    &:before {
      content: "";
      width: 1rem;
      left: 15%;
      height: 0.5rem;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: $color-blue;
      transform: translateY(3.6rem);
      border-radius: 1rem;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    }

    &:hover:before {
      content: "";
      background-color: $color-blue;
      height: 0.5rem;
      left: 15%;
      width: 70%;
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
<div class="navigation">
  <ul class="navigation__list">
    <li class="navigation__item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="navigation__item">Item 2</li>
    <li class="navigation__item">Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/nilo-c-sar-teixeira/pen/xxwLYgL